# Separation of forms & also drop down menu alteration when object selected

Tags: joomla, registration

In the image provided of my registration page, I wish to put a vertical separator inbetween the form on the left to have another form on the right to be completed for the registration but I have no idea how to do it.
    http://puu.sh/1FJIA
Also the second part of my question pertains to the drop down menu, how would I put an extra option other than #_usergroups that when selected will alter the drop down menu to change into a text box? Below is the coding used for the xml.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
<fieldset name="default"
    label="COM_USERS_REGISTRATION_DEFAULT_LABEL"
>

    <field name="spacer" type="spacer" class="text"
            label="COM_USERS_REGISTER_REQUIRED"
        />

    <field name="name" type="text"
        description="COM_USERS_REGISTER_NAME_DESC"
        filter="string"
        label="COM_USERS_REGISTER_NAME_LABEL"
        message="COM_USERS_REGISTER_NAME_MESSAGE"
        required="true"
        size="30"
    />

    <field name="username" type="text"
        class="validate-username"
        description="COM_USERS_DESIRED_USERNAME"
        filter="username"
        label="COM_USERS_REGISTER_USERNAME_LABEL"
        message="COM_USERS_REGISTER_USERNAME_MESSAGE"
        required="true"
        size="30"
        validate="username"
    />

    <field name="password1" type="password"
        autocomplete="off"
        class="validate-password"
        description="COM_USERS_DESIRED_PASSWORD"
        field="password2"
        filter="raw"
        label="COM_USERS_REGISTER_PASSWORD1_LABEL"
        message="COM_USERS_REGISTER_PASSWORD1_MESSAGE"
        required="true"
        size="30"
        validate="equals"
    />

    <field name="password2" type="password"
        autocomplete="off"
        class="validate-password"
        description="COM_USERS_REGISTER_PASSWORD2_DESC"
        filter="raw"
        label="COM_USERS_REGISTER_PASSWORD2_LABEL"
        message="COM_USERS_REGISTER_PASSWORD2_MESSAGE"
        required="true"
        size="30"
    />

    <field name="email1" type="email"
        description="COM_USERS_REGISTER_EMAIL1_DESC"
        field="id"
        filter="string"
        label="COM_USERS_REGISTER_EMAIL1_LABEL"
        message="COM_USERS_REGISTER_EMAIL1_MESSAGE"
        required="true"
        size="30"
        unique="true"
        validate="email"
    />

    <field name="email2" type="email"
        description="COM_USERS_REGISTER_EMAIL2_DESC"
        field="email1"
        filter="string"
        label="COM_USERS_REGISTER_EMAIL2_LABEL"
        message="COM_USERS_REGISTER_EMAIL2_MESSAGE"
        required="true"
        size="30"
        validate="equals"
    />

    <field name="title" type="sql" 
        default="-None Listed-"
        label="Select your University" 
        description="Select the University you are currently attending, if                                                   

it's not on the list then create it below"
        query="SELECT title FROM #__usergroups WHERE ID > '8    ' "
        required="true"
    />

    <field
        name="captcha"
        type="captcha"
        label="COM_USERS_CAPTCHA_LABEL"
        description="COM_USERS_CAPTCHA_DESC"
        validate="captcha"
    />

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want two separate forms and two separate submits on the same page?

You can make the layout whatever you want using a layout override.

Comment: have you atleast tried something of your own?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Vertical separator**:

you can use a hack i.e. create some fields which will output markup.

The idea here is to insert an extra

```
<div style='width:50%'>
```

before the first field;
Then a

```
</div><div style='width:49%;border-left:1px dashed black'>
```

where you want the separator
and finally a  at the end.

Create three new spacer fields.

You can either insert properly escaped html directly:

```
<field type="spacer" name="splitterinit" label="&lt;div&gt;" />
```

or put the html as language constants in the language file:

```
SPLITTER_MID="</div><div style='width:49%;border-left:1px dashed black'>"
```

and simply use the constant in the .xml:

```
<field type="spacer" name="splittermid" label="SPLITTER_MID" />
```

**2. Extra text option:**

- Easy: Simply add a text field below to allow the user to type in.
- Harder: Create a custom element, there you can write php and make it
  as you want it

**3. A word of advice**

Chronoforms features a user registration override that lets you define all the fields you want, and for sure you'll find more similar extensions on the JED
Also, all community solutions feature custom profiles.